# Realm.create will it update the object with the same primary key?

Tags: swift, realm

I am just curious, if I call `realm.create`, will it auto update `realm object from the realm results`?

```
// Assuming a "Book" with a primary key of `1` already exists.
try! realm.write {
realm.create(Book.self, value: ["id": 1, "price": 9000.0], update:   true)
// the book's `title` property will remain unchanged.
}
```

Currently it seems like I need to read from realm again to get the latest object. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, specifying `update: true` when calling `Realm.create(_:value:update:)` will result in the existing object being updated.

Here's a snippet based on the code you provided that demonstrates this:

```
class Book: Object {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var price = 0.0

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? { return "id" }
}


let realm = try! Realm()
let book = Book(value: ["1", "To Kill a Mockingbird", 9.99])
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(book)
}

let results = realm.allObjects(ofType: Book.self)

try! realm.write {
    realm.createObject(ofType: Book.self, populatedWith: ["id": "1", "price": 7.99], update: true)
}

print(book)
print(results)
```

This code produces the following output:

```
Book {
    id = 1;
    title = To Kill a Mockingbird;
    price = 7.99;
}
Results<Book> (
    [0] Book {
        id = 1;
        title = To Kill a Mockingbird;
        price = 7.99;
    }
)
```

As you can see the `price` property of the existing objects has updated to the new value.

Comment: Thanks for the verification & the detailed demo! It turns out that there's typo with my keys!

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles upon this question again, there are two ways to upsert for Realm in Swift. And to answer your question, both will result in the existing object being updated.

If you have the object, upsert with [`Realm.add(_:update:)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/Realm.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A0V3add_6updateySo0aB6ObjectC_AC12UpdatePolicyOtF).

```swift
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(bookToUpsert, update: .modified)
}
```

If you have JSON, use [`Realm.create(_:value:update:)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/Realm.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A0V6create_5value6updatexxm_ypAC12UpdatePolicyOtSo0aB6ObjectCRbzlF)

```swift
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(Book.self, value: ["id": "1", "price": 7.99], update: .modified)
}
```

I pass `.modified` to both, but update takes an [`UpdatePolicy`](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/Realm/UpdatePolicy.html). Which can be `.error`, `.modified`, `.all`.